# how to use v-if in laravel blade

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, laravel-blade

this is scripts part

```
 var practice3 = new Vue({
    el: "#practice3",
    data: {
        number: 2,
    }
});
```

and here I try to use number as if condition , but it does not work

```
  <div id="practice3">
                <p v-if="number > 5">if</p>
                <p v-else-if="number=10">else if</p>
                <p v-else>else</p>
            </div>
```

Comment: Which Vue.js version are you using? According to https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-else-if `v-else-if` was introduced in `2.1.0`. Also, `number = 10` sets the value of `number` to `10`, use `==` or `===` for comparison. With Vue.js >= `2.1.0` this works nicely (https://jsbin.com/coyadasobo/edit?html,output). Besides, this is not a Laravel but a Vue.js issue.

Comment: vue version is 2.6.12

Comment: Then change `number=10` to `number === 10`, does it work then?